# 1997 s10 4.3 misfire/dead cylinder

Tags: misfire, s10

I have a 97 s10 4.3 W vin with 273k miles that sat for 3-4 years due to a bad clutch. Recently replaced the clutch and fuel pump got it running and the #5 cylinder was dead no spark replaced all 6 plugs new plug wires cleaned the corrosion off the the distributor cap (the whole distributor was replaced not even a year before clutch went out) new egr line because it was kinked still stock egr valve. any ideas on what could be causing the misfire/dead cylinder? Pulled the intake off to replace the gasket because it was leaking coolant into the lifter valley, is it possible I missed a plug up top when putting it back together that would make it run like this?  No check engine light but also no scan tool to see if it’s throwing any codes

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest one of your valves is stuck open. You could check this by doing a compression check.

Comment: Re-reading your question, I see you say "no spark" ... is this an assumption on there being a dead cylinder (have you verified there is no spark firing) or is the cylinder just not firing. The latter is the basis for my above comment.

Comment: Did a compression test 160psi on all cylinders and put the timing light on all the plugs and #5 wasn’t sparking at first, after plugs and wires all 6 are sparking but still has a dead cylinder

Comment: Check the plug directly to see if it fires ... easiest way is to exchange it with another cylinder and see if the issue follows or sticks to your cylinder. Wouldn't be the first time I've seen a bad plug directly from the factory.

Comment: I’ll give it a shot later on today, I’m thinking it could possibly be a clogged injector. I’d go out and start it every now and then while it was sitting and it ran fine up until the fuel pump went bad and all the rust and gunk in the tank is was killed the pump but I’ve cleaned out the tank. It’s got injector cleaner in the tank and I let it run for a good while the other day and it didn’t clear up. If it’s not the spark plug my next go to would be a filter which honestly should’ve already been done then new injectors

Comment: It very well could be the spider. Check the easy things first.

Comment: 273K miles? What do you think is the usable life of this vehicle?  My guess is 185K to 200K miles.  Beyond that it becomes a money sink.  And fuel leaks from the spider are common with that vehicle. Just send money. Hint, probably best to not fall in love with your vehicle (Note: we've ALL been there and done that...me, too.) . With that said, there is a rule that at least once in your life you need to own a car that is older than you.  Get that done when you are young.  ha.